# k-nearest neighbor regression with replicated observations at each point

Tags: regression, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to formulate a regression problem where each training instance $x$ has multiple different observations of a response $y$. My goal is to predict the expected value of $y$ for new observations.

Where I'm having trouble is in handling the different sample sizes for each training instance. It seems to make sense that training instances with more samples are given more weight when performing the regression. I could treat each observation as a separate training instance, but I am curious if there are other options that would allow me to avoid storing each sample individually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... so you want to do k-nearest neighbour regression (mentioned in the title but not the text)? In standard regression there is a $y$ (response) to be predicted and one or more $x$-variables to predict. Are you saying that you have replicated observations with the same $x$ but potentially different $y$? This is how it seems to me, but it's somewhat different from what you write, when taken literally ("a set of observations for a particular response").

Comment: @Lewian yes, sorry it was unclear. As you said, I have replicated observations at the same $x$ but different values of $y$. I want to predict the expected value of $y$ for new instances of $x$.

Comment: If you do k-nearest neighbour, all observations at the same $x$ are nearest neighbours (distance 0), so you can use them all if there are more than $k$.

Comment: If $x$ is the nearest neighbor and there are more than $k$ replicates at $x$ does it make sense to use the overall mean response for the prediction?

Comment: Yes. (Apparently I have to type more than three letters for having my reply accepted... so be it then.)

Comment: I'm not sure that does make sense actually. I think typical applications use this, if you look for k neighbors but j neighbors all at the same distance from your record of interest (with j>k), the k records are chosen randomly from j as opposed to the average of all j. Whether or not averaging over all j is better or worse I'm not sure.